# como guardar en formato jpg una pagina hecha para imprimir en delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Con delphi 7 genero una impresion con imagen con  printer.BeguinDoc y printer.EndDoc

Eso generado preciso guardarlo en algun formato pdf, jpg o similar. Se puede hacer que en vez de impresora guarde en pdf pero son muchos con distintos titulos.

```
      PROCEDURE
 ** printer.BeginDoc;                     //  COMIENZA ARMAR PAGINA A IMPRIMIR  
      Imprime_Hoja                 ; //  PROCEDURE
      dec ( cant_hojas )           ;
     
  until cant_hojas < 1 ;         //
  printer.EndDoc;                     //  TERMINA PAGINA A IMPRIMIR
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes especificar mejor cual es tu problema?

Comment: La solución general es, en lugar de _dibujar_ sobre el canvas de la impresora, dibuja sobre el canvas de un mapa de bits, que luego puedes guardar como JPEG, por ejemplo. Para ello, tu código de _dibujo_ debe ser independiente del que elige el destino. Eso va a ser más fácil o difícil dependiendo de cómo esté escrito tu código, y sin ver, al menos una parte de ese código, es imposible escribir una respuesta en el formato de StackOverflow.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Se debe usar alguna libreria para esto en Delphi7??

Comment: No es necesario, publica al menos un fragmento de tu código para poder ayudarte. Un saludo.